# JSONP requests must use GET request method in angular 2

Tags: angular

above error i get when i'm  using jsonp with post method

To request on cross domain i have used jsonp but jsonp support only get method ,and i want to post method to cross domain in angular 2

here is my code

```
this._InstUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/' + listOfMedia[x].id + '/likes?access_token=' + this.hdnaccess_token;

                let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
                let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

                return this._jsonp.post(this._InstUrl, "", headers).map((res: Response) => { debugger; res.json() })
                                        .subscribe(
                                        (data) => {
                                            //if (this.Result.length == 0) { this.NoData = true; }
                                            debugger; console.log(this.Result);
                                        },
                                        (error) => {
                                            debugger; console.log(error);
                                        });
```

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Answer (score 1):

JSONP doesn't support other methods than `GET` and also doesn't support custom headers. This is not an Angular limitation but a JSONP limitation.

If you don't control the server and need more flexibility, use your own server to redirect CORS requests to the foreign server. CORS limitations only apply to the browser.

Comment: but im using instagram api

Comment: Not sure what to make of this comment. If the API is supposed to be used from browser applications not originally loaded from Instagram, use `Http` instead of `JSONP`.

Comment: when im going to use http it again give a me cross domain issue.can u provide any example for it to make api call with post method without getting cross domain isssue

Comment: If you get CORS errors, then it's not supposed to be used the way you do. Not sure why you accepted my answer. Because of the comment about redirecting on your own server. I think this is the best way to do what you want.